# Why do I get "JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs returned -1" error while loading the xlsx package in R?

Tags: java, r, xlsx

I just downloaded xlsx package in R, but I just can't use the library. (On Mac)

```
> library(xlsx)
JavaVM: requested Java version ((null)) not available. Using Java at "" instead.
JavaVM: Failed to load JVM: /bundle/Libraries/libserver.dylib
JavaVM FATAL: Failed to load the jvm library.
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'xlsx', details:
call: .jinit()
error: JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs returned -1

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘xlsx’
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have java installed? and the package rjava?

Comment: Yes, I installed java, and package rJava

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed the dependencies:

- xlsxjars
- rJava

And, of course, if that does not work, verify you have the Java JDK installed in your mac: `javac -version` If not, just install it from here: https://java.com/en/download/faq/java_mac.xml

Comment: Yes, I installed all of them.

Comment: Okay, it must be certainly something with the Java version. Look I found almost the same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34971966/how-does-one-configure-rjava-on-osx-to-select-the-right-jvm-jinit-failing 
Maybe you could keep track of this post and see if anyone can solve it, or maybe in the meanwhile I would try a new fresh java installation...?

Comment: Thank you sooooooo much! I will keep track of this post.