# Cannot load R xlsx package on Mac OS 10.11

Tags: java, r, macos

I can load the rJava and xlsxjars packages, but I get a "Failed to load JVM" when I execute library(xlsx). Below are my details.

OS Version:

```
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.11
BuildVersion:   15A284
```

Java Version:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
```

Java Path:

```
$ which java
/usr/bin/java
```

Java Home:

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home
```

R Version:

```
$ R --version
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10) -- "Wooden Christmas-Tree"
Copyright (C) 2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
```

How I launch R:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)/jre/lib/server: open -a RStudio
```

Loading the rJava and xlsxjars packages successfully:

```
> library(rJava)
> library(xlsxjars)
```

Unsuccessfully trying to load the xlsx package:

```
> library(xlsx)
JavaVM: requested Java version ((null)) not available. Using Java at "" instead.
JavaVM: Failed to load JVM: /bundle/Libraries/libserver.dylib
JavaVM FATAL: Failed to load the jvm library.
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'xlsx', details:
  call: .jinit()
  error: JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs returned -1
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘xlsx’
```

R Configuration:

```
Matts-MacBook-Pro:~ matt$ R CMD javareconf
Java interpreter : /usr/bin/java
Java version     : 1.8.0_65
Java home path   : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Java compiler    : /usr/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /usr/bin/javah
Java archive tool: /usr/bin/jar
Non-system Java on OS X

trying to compile and link a JNI program 
detected JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include/darwin
detected JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server -ljvm
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/../include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/../include/darwin -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
clang -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o conftest.so conftest.o -L/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server -ljvm -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation


JAVA_HOME        : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Java library path: $(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server
JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include/darwin
JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server -ljvm
Updating Java configuration in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
```

Comment: What gives `R CMD javareconf`?

Comment: Maybe the `read_excel` function from the `readxl` package might work as an alternative?

Answer (score 62):

Unfortunately, these symlink tricks didn't help me. However, I found a similar issue on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610293/how-to-get-rjava-0-9-3-to-work-on-os-x-10-7-4-with-oracle-java-1-7)! (where else ;))
This one worked for me by doing the following:

1. In terminal enter the following to relink Java correctly:

   ```
   sudo R CMD javareconf
   ```
2. Back in R (or RStudio) install the rJava package from source:

   ```
   install.packages("rJava",type='source')
   ```

Hope, this helps!

Comment: I had to do this afterwards for it to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738974/rjava-load-error-in-rstudio-r-after-upgrading-to-osx-yosemite

Comment: works after adding the link creation line by Tobias Mini

Comment: Per the link pointed to by ndimhypervol, I also had to run the following command sudo ln -f -s $(/usr/libexec/java_home)/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib /usr/local/lib

Comment: In step #2, needed to run as `sudo R` from terminal, and then `install.packages(...)`

Comment: did not work for me: configure: error: One or more JNI types differ from the corresponding native type. You may need to use non-standard compiler flags or a different compiler in order to fix this.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rJava’

Answer (score 14):

I ´ve got also problems with loading packages like openNLP, xlsx, RWeka, ... and got the same error message like you.
But finally this command worked for me on OS X 10.11.3: 
`sudo ln -s $(/usr/libexec/java_home)/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib /usr/local/lib`

Comment: `xlsx` not working for me on 10.12 Sierra. If I run that command it returns `ln: /usr/local/lib/libjvm.dylib: File exists` but I'm still getting the error

Answer (score 2):

There might be a problem in the version of Java for which the R xlsx package was built in. Some old software require to install the Java 6 for OS X 10.11 El Capitan, OS X 10.10 Yosemite, OS X 10.9 Mavericks, OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion, and OS X 10.7 Lion.
So you can try to install this old version of Java (Java for OS X 2015-001) at Apple website, link below:
https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=pt_BR&viewlocale=en_US

And check if you have a Java SE Development Kit 8. You can download it at Oracle website, link below:
[www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

I was having the same problem and downloading the old version of Java solved it.. I hope this help you!

Answer (score 1):

Basically, just do what is described here:
https://oliverdowling.com.au/2015/10/09/oracles-jre-8-on-mac-os-x-el-capitan/

short version:
d/l Java JRE from oracle as tar file
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html

then put this into you terminal (for sudo, your pw is needed):

```
cd ~/Downloads
tar -xzf `ls -1r jre-*-macosx-x64.tar.gz | head -1`
cd `ls -1rd jre*/ | head -1`
defaults write `pwd`/Contents/Info.plist JavaVM -dict-add 'JVMCapabilities' '<array><string>JNI</string><string>BundledApp</string><string>CommandLine</string></array>'
plutil -convert xml1 Contents/Info.plist
sudo mv `pwd` /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
mkdir -p Contents/Home/bundle/Libraries
cd Contents/Home/bundle/Libraries
ln -s ../../lib/server/libjvm.dylib libserver.dylib
```

works fine on my OS X 10.11

Comment: be very, very careful with this one -- that "sudo mv `pwd` /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines" line is going to move everything in `pwd` to that Java folder...

Comment: So I did this... and it crashed my computer of course, moving all my files into the JVM folder. How do I 'undo' it?

Warning to all others: DON'T DO THIS!!

Comment: Why mv pwd rather than `mv .`?

Comment: this is dangerous, you can break your system

Comment: This worked for me (using macOS Sierra Version 10.12, macbook pro 15-inch mid 2015 w/ 16GB ram - for anyone who has the same device)

Answer (score 0):

For me, MacOS Catalina 10.15.7, it was as simple as installing the current JRE and JDK software (downloaded as .dmg files from the official distributer websites on java.com and oracle.com - No affiliations whatsoever!).

I have also (re-) installed the rJava package, but I don't feel this was necessary. I actually simply did not have Java installed on my computer.

Now the `xlsx` package loads.