# Can't load package xlsx after upgrading to Sierra

Tags: r, rjava

I recently updated to Sierra and it seems like I can't load packages that depends on rJava anymore.

For example:

```
library(xlsx)
```

Gives:

```
Loading required package: rJava
Loading required package: xlsxjars
JavaVM: requested Java version ((null)) not available. Using Java at "" instead.
JavaVM: Failed to load JVM: /bundle/Libraries/libserver.dylib
JavaVM FATAL: Failed to load the jvm library.
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'xlsx', details:
  call: .jinit()
  error: JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs returned -1

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘xlsx’
```

Here is my sessions info:

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12
```

And Java is updated to the latest version (8.111).

Comment: This is a different error than I got with `rjava` when I upgraded to Yosemite, but, in case it might be useful, [here's a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738974/rjava-load-error-in-rstudio-r-after-upgrading-to-osx-yosemite) to the question I asked, in case the answers might be helpful.

Comment: @eipi10 `library('rJava')` doesn't retrieve any errors (from both RStudio and the terminal), thus I am not sure how to adapt the answers to your question. Have you upgraded to Sierra yet? Does everything works fine?

Comment: If you do not include the details of your JVM installation, then there's little that can be said. I doubt that there would be anything at `""` that could substitute for a properly installed Java library.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can understand from some similar [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610293/how-to-get-rjava-0-9-3-to-work-on-os-x-10-7-4-with-oracle-java-1-7) the java directories is not configured correctly.

You can solve this with terminal commands that fix the wrongly configured directories and there are multiple [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35179151/cannot-load-r-xlsx-package-on-mac-os-10-11) that use this strategy. But this can be rather confusing.

A much easier [strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342886/how-to-install-java-8-on-mac) that worked for me is to use [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) to install java. After installing Homebrew you can install java with the following commands

```
brew update
brew cask install java
```