# library(OpenStreetMap) loading error in R concerning Java

Tags: java, r, jvm, openstreetmap

I got the following messages in R when I tried to load OpenStreetMap library:

```
> library(OpenStreetMap)
Error in .jinit() : JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs returned -1

Error : loadNamespace()里算'OpenStreetMap'时.onLoad失败了，详细内容：
调用: fun(libname, pkgname)
错误: Java classes could not be loaded. Most likely because Java is not set up with your R installation.
Here are some trouble shooting tips:
1. Install Java 
2. Run 
    R CMD javareconf
in the terminal. If you are using Mac OS X >= 10.7 you may want to try
R CMD javareconf JAVA_CPPFLAGS=-I/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers
instead.

错误: ‘OpenStreetMap’程辑包或名字空间载入失败，
JavaVM: requested Java version ((null)) not available. Using Java at "" instead.
JavaVM: Failed to load JVM: /bundle/Libraries/libserver.dylib
JavaVM FATAL: Failed to load the jvm library.
```

My system is OS X El Capitan 10.11.5

```
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

Java Path

```
 $ which java
/usr/bin/java
```

R version

```
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03) -- "Supposedly Educational"
Copyright (C) 2016 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
```

I have tried the following, basically setting path and java environment in vi profile:

[rJava load error in RStudio/R after "upgrading" to OSX Yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738974/rjava-load-error-in-rstudio-r-after-upgrading-to-osx-yosemite)

[Cannot load R xlsx package on Mac OS 10.11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35179151/cannot-load-r-xlsx-package-on-mac-os-10-11)

[R: rJava package install failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311940/r-rjava-package-install-failing)

But I still cannot load library(OpenStreetMap) and got the warning messages above. p.s. I can load library(rJava) without problem.

Also, when I tried to install jvm packages, it shows:

```
package ‘jvm’ is not available (for R version 3.3.0)
```

Could anyone help shed some light on this question? Have been struggling with this issue for hours, and thanks sooooo much for your help.

---

I don't understand but it suddenly worked. But I could not load the map correctly:

```
> library(OpenStreetMap)
> map <- openmap(c(41,100),c(21,125),zoom=5,type = "osm")
There were 16 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> warnings()
警告信息：
1: In `[<-`(`*tmp*`, i, value = <S4 object of class structure("RasterStack", package = "raster")>) :
implicit list embedding of S4 objects is deprecated
2: In `[<-`(`*tmp*`, i, value = <S4 object of class structure("RasterStack", package = "raster")>) :
implicit list embedding of S4 objects is deprecated
```

Also, I have installed packages("raster").

Comment: those are just warnings, and the package examples give them, too, so you might not have to worry about them too much. Probably the package hasn't been updated to fix the [change in R 3.3.0](https://github.com/richarddmorey/BayesFactor/issues/73) If you're more concerned, send the [author](http://blog.fellstat.com/?cat=15) a message