# Issues installing RWeka

Tags: java, rweka

All,

I'm having some issues installing RWeka. I am on IOS 10.12.1.

This error message is appearing:

installing the source package ‘RWeka’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/RWeka_0.4-29.tar.gz'

Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 408921 bytes (399 KB)

==================================================

downloaded 399 KB

- installing *source* package ‘RWeka’ ...

** package ‘RWeka’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

** R

** inst

** preparing package for lazy loading

JavaVM: requested Java version ((null)) not available. Using Java at "" instead.

JavaVM: Failed to load JVM: /bundle/Libraries/libserver.dylib

JavaVM FATAL: Failed to load the jvm library.

Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'RWekajars', details:

call: .jinit()

error: JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs returned -1

ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘RWeka’

- removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/RWeka’

Warning in install.packages :

installation of package ‘RWeka’ had non-zero exit status

I've done the following to try to remedy the issue:

1. Re-installed rJava
2. Updated to Java; jre - 8u111 (64bit)
3. Downloaded the Java Developer Kit; jdk - 8u112 (64bit)
4. Updated R to 3.3.2
5. And tried this is Terminal; 
   sudo R CMD javareconf...
   sudo R install.packages("RWeka")
6. And restarted RStudio and did a restart of my iMac

Answer (score 6):

Run this first

> $ sudo R CMD javareconf

Then install rJava should work

> install.packages("rJava",type = "source")

You can then install

> install.packages("RWeka")

Hope this help.

Comment: This worked for me but I also had to use the solution posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738974/rjava-load-error-in-rstudio-r-after-upgrading-to-osx-yosemite

Answer (score 0):

Start R and try the following with root user:

```
sudo R CMD javareconf
...

sudo R 
> install.packages("RWeka")
```

Comment: Thanks caot, I've tried that before as well with not luck.

Comment: @JoshuaPeterson You can try the solution mentioned at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35179151/cannot-load-r-xlsx-package-on-mac-os-10-11

Comment: if it didn't work: the `sudo R CMD javareconf` must be executed in the terminal, whereas the `install.packages("RWeka")` must be executed in Rstudio.

Comment: @AgileBean  install.packages("RWeka") can also be executed in terminal