# RWeka installation under Rstudio on Mac

Tags: r, rweka

I tried to find solutions from previous posts, but they do not solve my problem.

I am using macOS High Sierra and have Java installed. Below is the error reported by Rstudio. Also, rJava, Mac, and R are really messy with each other. I found this post but still does not work.

https://github.com/MTFA/CohortEx/wiki/Run-rJava-with-RStudio-under-OSX-10.10,-10.11-(El-Capitan)-or-10.12-(Sierra)

///////////////////

> library(RWeka)
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RWeka’:
>    .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
>     call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
>     error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
>     dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libjvm.dylib
>     Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
>     Reason: image not found
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   package ‘RWeka’ was built under R version 3.4.4

Comment: could you please run `library(rJava)` just for verification?

Answer (score 0):

I met the same question and I found this is helpful.
[Cannot load R xlsx package on Mac OS 10.11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35179151/cannot-load-r-xlsx-package-on-mac-os-10-11)

> 1.In terminal enter the following to relink Java correctly:
>
> ```
> sudo R CMD javareconf
> ```
>
> 2.Back in R (or RStudio) install the rJava package from source:
>
> ```
> install.packages("rJava",type='source')
> ```

Then 
    `library(rJava)`
and 
    `library(RWeka)`
should work.