# rJava installation fails on macOS 10.14

Tags: r, rjava, macos-mojave

After upgrading to MacOS Mojave (10.14.1), I'm no longer able to install `rJava` for R version 3.5.1 with Java version "1.8.0_102" installed.

I tried the [previous solution for MacOS 10.11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35179151/cannot-load-r-xlsx-package-on-mac-os-10-11) but it still did not work, giving this error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
.onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
 call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
 error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
 dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib
 Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
 Reason: image not found
```

Answer (score 6):

Posting the solution I found in case it helps others -- I don't quite understand why this work or if it's the right way so looking for better alternatives!

This [issue](https://github.com/frida/frida/issues/338) lead to [this Apple forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/104296) where it's stated

> For legacy software that looks for the macOS headers in the base system under /usr/include, please install the package file located at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14. pkg

To do this, open terminal and run these commands

```
cd /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/
open macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```

then follow prompts to install the package.

After this, in the terminal, configure rJava and install as in the previous answer

`sudo R CMD javareconf`

`R -e "install.packages('rJava')"`

and it should install without problem.

Comment: You may need to install the CommandLineTools directory as well. That can be performed with 'sudo xcode-select --install'.

Comment: Thanks @PeterN.Steinmetz -- I did try that (following some other link) without success...though I think it was necessary for the above to work.

Answer (score 2):

After installing JDK 11.04 LTS I rain into the same error in R Studio on Mojave

R was expecting `Library not loaded: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk`

Despite running `sudo R CMD javareconf` the error still persisted

Therefore I browsed to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` in finder and renamed the folder `"jdk-11.0.4.jdk"` to `"jdk-11.0.1.jdk"`

Restarted R and both `library(rJava)` and `library(xlsx)` now work.

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the exact problem. I solved it by:

1. Install the [latest version of Java](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk12-downloads-5295953.html) (dmg file)
2. Install rJava in Studio: install.packages("rJava")
3. In the terminal:  `sudo mv jdk-12.0.1.jdk jdk-11.0.1.jdk`

Otherwise the following error will appear in Rstudio:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
  Reason: image not found
```

4. In Rstudio: `library(rJava)`
5. rJava should have been loaded without issues.

Comment: Glad to know that this works. I'd be a little concerned about overwriting the version of Java...presumably there are actual differences. At the least, I wonder if you could make a symlink instead of actually renaming the entire directory?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into same issue, when i was trying to install "rJava" in my macOs (Mojave version).

Below steps i executed to resolve issue.

R version : 3.6.1

issue : configure: error: one or more Java tools are missing.
*** JDK is incomplete! Please make sure you have a complete JDK. JRE is *not* sufficient.

solution : execute below command in your terminal

1. `$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V`

```
    Matching Java Virtual Machines (1):
        1.8.0_162, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_221.jdk(your Java version)/Contents/Home
```

1. `$ export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_221.jdk/Contents/Home`
2. `$ export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH`
3. `$ R CMD javareconf`
4. `$ R --quiet -e 'install.packages("rJava", type="source", repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org")'`