# Mac os rJava install error about jdk version

Tags: java, r, macos

[image]
I have to install rJava and I`m using mac Os. but I met a problem. That is, I am using jdk1.8.0_221 but I think rJava try to load jdk11 like this picture. I don't now how can i resolve it. If you have a idea about this problem help me. thank you!

Comment: It would be helpful to know more about the Mac OS you are using etc. Have you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53502439/rjava-installation-fails-on-macos-10-14

Comment: another related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738974/rjava-load-error-in-rstudio-r-after-upgrading-to-osx-yosemite