# Error in Installation of RWeka package in R

Tags: r

I have been trying to install the RWeka package in my RStudio  (Version 0.99.902) but it keeps on giving the error below.  My OS is Mac OS Sierra Version 10.12.

Any insights or leads would be extremely appreciated.

```
> install.packages("RWeka", lib="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library")

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
      binary source needs_compilation
RWeka 0.4-26 0.4-31             FALSE

installing the source package ‘RWeka’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/RWeka_0.4-31.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 409473 bytes (399 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 399 KB

* installing *source* package ‘RWeka’ ...
** package ‘RWeka’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
JavaVM: requested Java version ((null)) not available. Using Java at "" instead.
JavaVM: Failed to load JVM: /bundle/Libraries/libserver.dylib
JavaVM FATAL: Failed to load the jvm library.
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'RWekajars', details:
  call: .jinit()
  error: JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs returned -1

ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘RWeka’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/RWeka’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RWeka’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/p7/z0g7bxzx4sq93z0r974xyrvh0000gn/T/RtmpnB7den/downloaded_packages’
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40142387/5451344) to reconfigure rJava and then re-compile from source (even though rJava was already installed with no errors).  After doing that, the RWeka installation worked.  I am on MacOS 10.10.5.

```
sudo ln -s $(/usr/libexec/java_home)/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib /usr/local/lib
sudo R CMD javareconf
```

Then in R:

```
install.packages("rJava", type = "source")
install.packages("RWeka", type = "source")
```