# Error installing rJava on mac OSX 10.12.4

Tags: java, r, macos

I'm trying to install the [xlsx](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/index.html) package on my mac, but I keep getting the error

> JavaVM FATAL: Failed to load the jvm library

So, I've tried to follow the advice found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40142387/2146894), but I get hung up on the last step - installing [rJava](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rJava/index.html).  The error message(s) I get are

```
> install.packages("rJava",type='source')
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rJava_0.9-8.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 656615 bytes (641 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 641 KB

* installing *source* package ‘rJava’ ...
** package ‘rJava’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for gcc... /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/private/var/folders/nz/5zx8zy7d1yg4fxhtttcl7s_c0000gn/T/RtmpB2wCzM/R.INSTALL139d1a450fb0/rJava':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rJava’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/rJava’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/rJava’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rJava’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/nz/5zx8zy7d1yg4fxhtttcl7s_c0000gn/T/RtmpD4AWyg/downloaded_packages’
```

Prior to this, when I run `sudo R CMD javareconf` I get

```
Java interpreter : /usr/bin/java
Java version     : 1.8.0_25
Java home path   : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Java compiler    : /usr/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /usr/bin/javah
Java archive tool: /usr/bin/jar
Non-system Java on macOS

trying to compile and link a JNI program 
detected JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include/darwin
detected JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server -ljvm
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/../include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/../include/darwin -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib -o conftest.so conftest.o -L/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server -ljvm -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation


JAVA_HOME        : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Java library path: $(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server
JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include/darwin
JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server -ljvm
Updating Java configuration in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
Done.
```

Any tips for fixing this issue?

Comment: The error states the `C` compiler isn't working... maybe post the contents of `config.log`, as it might glean more information.

Comment: Hmm I can't find `config.log`.  Any suggestion where to look for it?

Comment: Try checking in `/private/var/folders/nz/5zx8zy7d1yg4fxhtttcl7s_c0000gn/T/RtmpD4AWyg/` or in Console.app.

Comment: No luck finding it, unfortunately : /

Comment: Maybe try your users home directory also...

Comment: Did you install xcode? Get it in the appstore

Comment: @LevKuznetsov yes, I have xcode

Comment: How did you install R in the first place? When installed via brew it usually takes care of things like this

Comment: I downloaded R-3.3.3.pkg and went through the installation like I usually do.

Comment: Same issue, I assume you might be trying to do a process like this to knit up R with the JVM install? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26948777/how-can-i-make-rjava-use-the-newer-version-of-java-on-osx